# Guardar el estado de un botón dentro de un recyclerview

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, sharedpreferences

Estoy tratando de guardar el estado de un botón dentro de un adaptador con `SharedPrederences` en `Android`, parcialmente lo he conseguido pero, resulta que el cambio se ejecuta en todos los botones, adjunto una imagen para explicarme mejor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pantalla principal es un `Fragment` que se muestra dentro del `MainActivity`, trate de utilizar el método add() en lugar del replace() pero, no solucionaría que al cerrar la aplicación se mantengan los estados del botón, de antemano muchas gracias por su tiempo.

```
public class RecipesAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecipesAdapter.RecipesViewHolder> {
    View view;
    Context context;
    List<RecipesVo> listRecipes;
    //RecyclerItemClick itemClick;
    IComunicaFragments itemClick;

    public RecipesAdapter(List<RecipesVo> listRecipes, IComunicaFragments itemClick, Context context) {
        this.listRecipes = listRecipes;
        this.itemClick = itemClick;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecipesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list_recipe, parent, false);

        return new RecipesViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecipesViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //declare recyclerview false to recycle
        //holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

        //declare list position
        RecipesVo recipes = listRecipes.get(position);

        //declare list fav

        //declare connection to fill elements
        holder.imgThumbnail.setImageResource(recipes.getIdThumbnail());
        holder.txtRecipeName.setText(recipes.getRecipeName());
        holder.txtRecipeTime.setText(recipes.getTimePrepare());
        holder.txtRecipeDifficult.setText(recipes.getDifficultPrepare());

        //declare button fav and state
        setButtonStatus(holder, recipes);

        //implement the onClick interface
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            //itemClick.itemClick(recipes);
            itemClick.sendRecipe(recipes);
        });
    }

    private void setButtonStatus(RecipesViewHolder holder, RecipesVo recipes) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Utilities.PREFS_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        recipes.setSelected(preferences.getBoolean(Utilities.BOOLEAN_KEY, Boolean.parseBoolean("")));

        if (recipes.getSelected()) {
            holder.btnAddFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_btn_fav_selected);
        } else {
            holder.btnAddFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_btn_fav_unselected);
        }

        holder.btnAddFav.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            //change background button
            pressedBtn(holder, recipes);
        });
    }

    private void pressedBtn(RecipesViewHolder holder, RecipesVo recipes) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Utilities.PREFS_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor objEditor = preferences.edit();

        if (!recipes.getSelected()) {
            recipes.setSelected(true);
            holder.btnAddFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_btn_fav_selected);
            //Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Added:", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            itemClick.keepFav(recipes);
            //saveRecipe(recipes);
        } else {
            recipes.setSelected(false);
            holder.btnAddFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_btn_fav_unselected);
            //Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Deleted:", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            itemClick.deleteFav(recipes);
            //deleteRecipe(recipes);
        }

        objEditor.putBoolean(Utilities.BOOLEAN_KEY, recipes.getSelected());
        objEditor.apply();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listRecipes.size();
    }

    public static class RecipesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //declare items to click
        CardView cardRecipe;
        ImageButton btnAddFav;

        //declare items to fill
        TextView txtRecipeName, txtRecipeTime, txtRecipeDifficult;
        ImageView imgThumbnail;

        public RecipesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //items onclick
            cardRecipe = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_recipes);
            btnAddFav = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_fav_list);

            //items to fill
            imgThumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);
            txtRecipeName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_recipe_name_list);
            txtRecipeTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_time_list);
            txtRecipeDifficult = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_prepare_list);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa SQLite, de ese modo vas a poder tener guardado varios datos sin tener que saber si es que esta guardado o no. Te comparto un pequeño codigo sencillo para que lo apliques, no necesitas de permisos de almacenamiento para poder usar SQLite.

Recuerda editar el codigo a tu gusto.

//La clase para poder usar tu base de datos

```
public class SQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String NOMBRE = "TODO"; //Nombre de tu base de datos
    private static final int VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLA = "CREATE TABLE todo(nota TEXT, fecha TEXT)"; //Codigo para crear tu base de datos en lenguaje de SQL

    public SQLite(Context context){
        super(context, NOMBRE, null, VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(TABLA);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLA);
        db.execSQL(TABLA);
    }

    public void addNote(String Note, String Date){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        if (db != null){
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO todo VALUES('"+Note+"', '"+Date+"')");
            db.close();
        }
    }

    public void deleteNote(String Note){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        if (db != null){
            db.execSQL("DELETE FROM todo WHERE nota='"+Note+"'");
            db.close();
        }
    }

    public void editNote(String oldNote, String newNote, String Date){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        if (db != null){
            db.execSQL("UPDATE todo SET nota='"+newNote+"', fecha='"+Date+"' WHERE nota='"+oldNote+"'");
            db.close();
        }
    }

    public List<TodoNoteModel> getNotes(){
        List<TodoNoteModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM todo", null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do {
                    list.add(new TodoNoteModel(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1)));
                } while(cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            list.add(new TodoNoteModel(e.getMessage(), e.toString()));
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

// Modelo de Ejemplo

```
public class TodoNoteModel {

    private String Nota, Date;

    public TodoNoteModel(){}

    public TodoNoteModel(String Nota, String Date){
        this.Nota = Nota;
        this.Date = Date;
    }

    public String getNota() {
        return Nota;
    }

    public void setNota(String nota) {
        Nota = nota;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return Date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        Date = date;
    }
}
```

// Ejemplo al agregar una nota

```
SQLite sqlite = new SQLite(TodoActivity.this);
sqlite.addNote(input.getText().toString(), getDate());
```

// Ejemplo para borrar una nota

```
SQLite sqlite = new SQLite(TodoActivity.this);
sqlite.deleteNote(note.get(position).getNota());
```

// Ejemplo para editar una nota

```
SQLite sqlite = new SQLite(TodoActivity.this);
sqlite.editNote(note.get(position).getNota(), input.getText().toString(), getDate());
```

// Y finalmente obtener los datos guardados

```
SQLite sqlite = new SQLite(this);
List<TodoNoteModel> list = sqlite.getNotes();
```

Te recomiendo actualizar el RecyclerView una vez actualizado los datos. Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pues si utilice SQLite para cargar todas las recetas cuando se inicia la app y luego lo lleno en el Recycler; igualmente para los corazones ahora utilizo un dato en la clase POJO que se actualiza cada vez que alguien hace click,

Comment: Excelente! Suerte en tu app :)